# Why is this callback executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want a validation to run before a record gets updated. I know of `before_update` but I pretty much copy and pasted the first codesnippet out of the api docs.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

My stripped down model looked then like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
  validates :email, :presence => true

  before_save(:on => :update) do
    puts "******** before_save on => :update ********"
    # do something
  end
end
```

if I go into the console and do create a **new** entry this callback is being executed on a SQL insert call.

```
irb(main):001:0> User.new(:email => "test@test.com").save
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
******** before_save on => :update ********
SQL (29.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 30 Mar 2012 00:26:33 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test@test.com"], ["first_name", nil], ["last_name", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 30 Mar 2012 00:26:33 UTC +00:00]]
   (433.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
```

I would have expected to see this only on an update call. Can anybody sheed some light on this?

[EDIT]

I just changed the callback into a function call with no change in the outcome. The callback is still executed on create.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :email
validates :email, :presence => true

before_save :my_before_update, :on => :update

private

def my_before_update
    puts "******** before_save on => :update ********"
    # do something
end
```

end

The output is the same.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.2)
irb(main):001:0> User.new(:email => "test@test.com").save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
******** before_save on => :update ********
  SQL (28.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "first_name", "last_name",         "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 30 Mar 2012 02:28:45 UTC +00:00],     ["email", "test@test.com"], ["first_name", nil], ["last_name", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 30     Mar 2012 02:28:45 UTC +00:00]]
   (131.2ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Comment: Same behavior in a regular running application.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but I don't see anything in the docs about passing `(:on => :update)` to before_save, and why not use `before_update`?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I know that there is a `before_update`, but it happened today that I had the docs open when I needed exactly this and it did not work. the `:on` is explained for validations in the guides -> http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on  the callbacks come right after it and the docs mention the the `:on` pattern again. So I pulled the strings...

Comment: Looks like :on is for validations, i.e. `validates :email, :presence => true, :on => :update` would only validate email on update, I still don't see anything that says `before_save` should take the :on option.

Comment: `update` and `save` are not very different in the context of validation and callbacks... why parameterize `save` at all if it's the only thing I can pass to `before_save(:on =>` ?

Comment: If i understand your question right (im not sure i do) `before_save` would run each time the record is saved, `before_update` would not run the first time the record is created, but would run every time the record is updated or saved after that.

Comment: and `:on` seems to be reserved for validations `before_validation(:on => :create)` but not any of the `before_save` or `before_update` callbacks

Comment: This is not a real problem, since I ended up using `before_update` anyways... I was just curious about it, since it looked naturally to me to allow such a construct. I guess I was just looking for an explanation which I got =)

thx for all comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ActiveRecord::Callbacks don't support an `:on` option...

From the Rails codebase, the only place that mentions handling an `:on` option is in the validations module code in [ActiveModel::Validations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.2/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L73).

If you look through the [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb) code, you'll see that there's no mention of `:on`, nor does the ActiveRecord::Callbacks module include any of the ActiveModel::Validations module that will handle that option. There is an include for ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks, but that will just provide the definitions for the `before_` and `after_` validations methods. However, the `before_validation` and `after_validation` callbacks will handle the `:on` option as seen [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.2/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb#L29) in their definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is one of those areas that the Rails API has changed across versions. I do recall there being a way to pass `:on` as an option to `before_save`, just as I recall when you had to define an `after_initialize` method (it wasn't available as a callback).

The current way is cleaner and more explicit.

If you do find that the current docs reference `before_save(:on => :update)`, check out the new [docrails](https://github.com/lifo/docrails) Github repository where you can fork, change, and **commit** changes to the docs to be included (no pull requests necessary, or accepted).

Comment: Thanx for the link. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research, looks like you're right, it looks like you can pass `:on => :update` to `before_save`

Maybe the issue comes from the block notation, try calling a function like this:

```
before_save :run_this_before_update, :on => :update

def run_this_before_update
  puts "******** before_save on => :update ********"
  # do something
end
```

Looks like a major reason to use this is the order in which Rails runs the callbacks, check out this most excellent article from pivotallabs http://pivotallabs.com/users/danny/blog/articles/1767-activerecord-callbacks-autosave-before-this-and-that-etc-

Comment: I just changed it to a function call. Same results. The callback is executed on create. Thanx for the link though. I go and check it out.

Comment: I just got back from the blogpost you mentioned and there is something wrong about what he's doing there... His relation says, that his current_model `belongs_to :credit_card` and has a callback `before_create :build_credit_card`

This means, the child object `current_model` creates the parent on a callback... which is most likley wrong. foreign_key constraints are wrong too then, which screws up the order on which end of the relation things get called and stuff.

Comment: @mober, re: the blog post, if they save the Credit Card in the callback first and assign that to the current model, then the `belongs_to` relationship will autosave that relationship. So, it's a valid way to build that...

Comment: @Alex, just the fact that they moved the `before_save ... :on => :create` before the `belongs_to` probably fixed the issue, if what he says is true about a `belongs_to` being transformed to a `before_save`, because then Rails is just executing the callbacks in sequence. The `:on => :create` is just ignored because it's not a supported option...

Comment: Ya i opened an app and tried every variation i could think of with the :on option, nothing seems to work.  Also as you said @mober, looks like that article had a different case in mind, I guess I really don't see a good reason to need to pass the :on option then.

Comment: @mober, I agree the relationship is that the CurrentModel belongs_to the CreditCard. But, that's just the association... as long as the CreditCard gets created before the CurrentModel, it's still valid. For example, let's say the CurrentModel is a ProductOrder. When you go to the site, and you add some stuff to your shopping cart, and you go to checkout... you have an instance of a ProductOrder. But, maybe you've never given this site your CreditCard before. So, before saving the ProductOrder, the site needs to create your CreditCard first, then assign the ProductOrder to that card.

Comment: @kafuchau I hear what you're saying but I disagree, I might be wrong though ;)
What could belong to a credit_card, that creates a credit card on its own creation? Things like shipping_address or billing_address belong to credit_card and they should get created in the context of creating the credit_card and not vice-versa.

Comment: @kafuchau
Sorry for messing things up but I cannot edit comments... 
Your example makes perfect sense right now and I was wrong. I simply didn't think of this situation...